# MariaDB SQL syntax near error parenthesis ')' for python

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

I am trying to insert some data into my MariaDB using python script.
when I do the following in console it works perfectly.

```
INSERT INTO `Failure` (`faillure_id`, `testrun_id`, `failed_at`, `log_path`, `node`) 
         VALUES   (2, 1, 'STEP8:RUN:RC=1', '/var/fail_logs','NodeA')
```

shows me a query ok. and I can see the table being populated. no problem there.

However when I do the same SQL query using python I get some error.
Here's my code

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","user","","DB")
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO `Failure` (`testrun_id`, `failed_at`, `log_path`, `node`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)""",(testrun_id, failed_at, log_path, node))
conn.commit()
```

this yields the following error

> check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '),

Can someone please help me understand where the error is coming from.

Comment: Just as a thought, is this the only query that gets run? Could this error be thrown in a different place?

Comment: @ChrisForrence Hello Chris, I have tested this query several times and every time it fails. However sometimes the query works as long as the number of argument is less than 3. I'm using a work around for now. I have put my work around in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

As a work-around I'm building the query string like this

```
sql_query = "INSERT INTO `Failure` (`testrun_id`, `failed_at`, `log_path`, `node`) VALUES " + "( '" + str(testrun_id) + "', '" + str(failed_at) + "', '"+ log_path + "', '" + node + "')"
cursor.execute(sql_query)
```

not very efficient but does the job for now.

Comment: Without escaping, you are leaving yourself open to SQL Injection.

Comment: Yes, its a work-around for now. I have yet to figure out why is it happening. I tried the same code with little php script and phpmyadmin just to test it out..turns out no error exists.